# Protractor getAttribute promise - resolving value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, protractor

We have the following problem, we want to store a value from the getAttribute function in a local variable. We try to resolve the promise but it won't work.

```
return element(by.id('foo')).getAttribute('value');
```

This will return a promise and we are trying to store the value like

```
let result = await element(by.id('foo')).getAttribute('value');
```

But this will only give another promise object back. I also tried to resolve it by chaining promises like this:

```
static async  getStreetNumberAsync() {
       this.getStreetNumber().then(function(value) {
            return new Promise.resolve(value);
       });
   }
```

And then again wait for the promise to be resolved but that didn't work either. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to handle this? 
The whole code:

```
static getStreetNumber(){
       return this.MPP().txtStreetNumber.getAttribute('value');
}

static async  getStreetNumberAsync() {
       let value = await this.getStreetNumber();
       return value;
}

static  editMyProfile(){
       let value = this.getStreetNumberAsync();
}
```

the value of 'value' will be a promise [object promise]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the definition of `element` function? If it returns the element asynchronously you can try to wrap the await in bracelets `(await element(by.id('foo'))).getAttribute('value');`

Comment: Of course, you will get a promise. You need to embrace asynchrony: you must *keep* using `then` or `await` in the surrounding code as well. You cannot expect the promised (future) result to suddenly be available already *now*. That is the whole crux of asynchrony.

Comment: Value is still a promise, if i do let a = (await element(by.id('foo'))).getAttribute('value');. When I log it to the console I get a list of all functions that the promise contains

Answer (score 0):

You've already got an `async` function - use it:

```
static async getStreetNumberAsync() {
  let value = await this.getStreetNumber();
  return value;
}
```

Or if you want a Promise:

```
return new Promise(resolve => resolve(value));
```

Comment: Don't I have to await on the this.getStreetNumber()?

Comment: Yes @John fixed!

Comment: It didn't do the trick... I have updated my original post to give you a better idea how it looks like right now.